# Gantt Chart Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, gantt-chart, anychart, oracle-jet

I need some help in creating a Gantt chart in Oracle Apex. In a previous release, the AnyChart Flash .swf files were removed from the /images folder. This results in your charts no longer rendering. No error message displays and the region is blank.
I researched a lot, I found only this:
Use the Application Upgrade utility to quickly upgrade AnyChart components in an application to JET Chart.

To use the Application Upgrade utility:

1. On the Workspace home page, click the App Builder icon.
   The App Builder home page appears.
2. Select an application.
3. Click Utilities.
4. Click Upgrade Application.
5. Under Upgrade Type, review the list for one of the following messages:

   ```
    "Upgrade AnyChart Charts to Oracle JET Charts"
    "Upgrade Flash Charts to HTML5 Charts"
   ```
6. If either message appears, click the adjacent number in the Candidate Objects column to view pages containing these components.
7. Select objects to convert using the check box column and click the Upgrade button (top-right).
   A success message appears, and the selected objects update and disappear from the list.

When I reach step 5, I do not get any of these messages. Please any help.
I don't know how to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JET Charts are the native Oracle Apex charts. Oracle suggests using them instead of third-party products. For Apex v18 and lower, you can use [AnyChart plugins](https://www.anychart.com/technical-integrations/samples/oracle-apex/). For v19 and higher version, you can use [the latest version of the AnyChart JS library](https://docs.anychart.com/Quick_Start/Quick_Start) as custom HTML content in the layout.